# Tips about MySQL installation

Tags: mysql

I'm starting to prepare my server for a classic configuration Apache PhP MySQL.

- I installed Apache 2.2.24 without problems. (Output "It works").
- I installed php 5.2.1 - win32 - installer. (launching info.php I see I see all configuration details).

Now I have to install MySQL.

Question:

Which version do you recommend suitable for Apache 2.2.24 and PHP 5.2.1.
You could attach the link?

P.s.: only classic configuration (no wamp or others).

Comment: Why do you use this versions? The end of life of php 5.2 is 2011  http://php.net/releases/

Comment: I recommend all those who start study apache,php and mysql youtube.com/watch?v=mvt9P9HWWqg . I've tried it and it really works and guides you step by step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Load them all at once - WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/).  Their current version has 64-bits (or 32-bits) with

- Apache 2.4.9
- MySQL 5.6.17
- PHP 5.5.12
- PHPMyAdmin 4.1.14
- SqlBuddy 1.3.3
- XDebug 2.2.5

That should be easier and better than installing end-of-life software.

Comment: Hi Rick thanks to your support but is very hard configure all. Tomorrow I try for 3 time... I hope with succes. Do you know a manual?

Comment: Sorry.  Wamp (and probably most others) are not as straight-forward as they should be.  In PHP, you have to manually turn on various 'extensions' (such as mysqli and/or PDO).  I have installed Wamp at home at least 3 times, always take some trial and error.

Comment: Wamp bundles the things together.  IIS only cares about .net, Access/SqlServer, so I would expect more hassles.

Comment: Thanks Rick, I was able to configure my server for development and testing. I recommend all those who start study apache,php and my sql this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvt9P9HWWqg . I've tried it and it really works and guides you step by step.

Comment: I installed Apache 2.4.16 VC11 (64bit), Php 5.5.28 VC11 (64 bit), mySQL installer community 5.6.17 and Microsoft expression Web.  Now I want to install PHP My Admin, can you suggest a link? Best regards.

Answer (score -1):

I am running a similar configuration (but under Linux) and would recommend 5.5.45 available here:- http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Comment: Why not the latest (5.6) ?

Comment: Based on set up I have which is similar to OP. As  a new set up it would be sensible to go for latest PHP and MySQL...